# Oracle Concurrency Handling

Tags: multithreading, oracle, oracle11g

I have multi thread environment(Multiple Nodes),where each thread calls a select query which has n rows eligible,but I have configure rownum<6,followed by a update for the same 5 records selected.These are done in a single transaction through java program.

My Requirement:- 
while these 5 records are processed bye one thread in one process,all other thread need to pick 5 records each from n-5 records and process ?

If 2 threads has been initiated at same time how I can handle the situation? So two threads are going to pick different data set.

Oracle Version :- 11.2.0.2.0

Comment: Look at the docs for "select for update" with "skip locked".

Comment: @Mat I read about the for update skip lock.But still I am not clear if 2 threads come at a same with(With same select query with same parameter along with for update skip lock) ,how it got prioritised ?

Comment: So the first query will select and lock the first 5 records. The second query will skip those, because they are locked, and select the next 5.

Comment: How you decide which one is first ,if both has been triggered at same time, there is no difference in milliseconds also?

Comment: Transactional databases know how to deal with that.

Comment: @Mat Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Mat Can you please provide a link where I can read about this.